# What does "due to" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

A sentence from a news webpage (http://www.reuters.com/article/us-italy-quake-toll-idUSKCN1110FV):

> A day of national mourning was announced, with flags due to fly at half mast around the country for the dead, who include a number of foreigners.

What does "due to" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Due, in this case means ["scheduled" or "expected"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/due#Adjective). The word "to" is part of the infinitive verb "to fly". The Italian government has asked for flags to be lowered halfway down flagpoles as a mark of mourning.

This is not "due to" meaning "because of"

Answer (score 2):

This is not a prepositional verb or preposition in this case. It is [due] [to fly].

> [due](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due)
>   : required or expected to happen : expected to be in a particular place at a particular time

So it is expected that the flags will fly at half mast.